# Force Storyboard to present specific base localization

Tags: ios, localization, storyboard, xcode5

I have a story board with base localisation (The story board itself is not localised)
I wish to use base locazation to localize the app and still to be able to change the localization from within the app itself.

Right now I am dong so with this approach -

```
+(NSString*)localizedStringForKey:(NSString*) key
{
    NSBundle* languageBundle = [self localizationBundle];
    NSString* str=[languageBundle localizedStringForKey:key value:@"" table:nil];
    return str;
}
```

**But** this works only for dynamic strings that I assign in the code.
Is there any way to force the story board to use specific base localizatio or should I give up using this option and create all the strings in code ?

Thanks
SHani

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the same method for storyboards as you did for strings:

```
// Utils class...
+ (NSString *)localizedStoryboardForName:(NSString *)key
{
    NSBundle *languageBundle = [self localizationBundle];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:key bundle:languageBundle];
    return storyboard;
}
```

If you have main storyboard defined in project's plist, remove that record and create explicitly in **AppDelegate**.

```
// AppDelegate class...
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [Utils localizedStoryboardForName:@"Main"];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[self.window setRootViewController:[storyboard instantiateInitialViewController]];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Then create storyboards with different languages inside. They should be localised in the same way as **Localizable.strings** files.

Comment: @Artel Stepanenko This does not work if you have enabled Size Classes for your Storyboard and if you are using Localizable Strings for your Storyboard translations. In that case an exception is raised ("There doesn't seem to be a valid compiled storyboard at path..."). Any ideas how to deal with this issue?